# Angular2+ memory leaks while using Subscribers and subscribe.first()

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Im working with an Angular2 app which is run via electron.
Currently I'm looking to improve performance for the app and reduce memory leaks. I understand that you need to destroy subscribers when the app is destroyed to prevent them watching for new values. But do you need to destroy a subscription which runs only once?

```
ObservableVar.subscribe().first((ans) => { // Wanting to use only one ans
    dostuff(ans);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't need to destroy a subscription that runs only once as the observable will complete by itself. This is the same if you use `take(1)`.

Here is the RxJS doc about [first](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/first.html) and [take](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/take.html).

You have to use them like this:

```
myOvservable.pipe(first()).subscribe(value => { /* do something */ });
myOvservable.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(value => { /* do something */ });
```

If you have multiple subscriptions to unsubscribe from, it may be worthwhile to use the `takeUntil` trick. You create a subject in which you feed a dummy value when you want your observables to complete:

```
unsubscribe = new Subject<void>();

myObs1.pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)).subscribe(value => { /* do something */ });
myObs2.pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)).subscribe(value => { /* do something */ });

// trigger the unsubscription
this.unsubscribe.next();
```

> Note: `takeUntil` should be the last operator in the pipe sequence in order to avoid leaks ([see this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-avoiding-takeuntil-leaks-fb5182d047ef)).

You can also use the `Subscription` class to manage your subscriptions:

```
subscriptions = new Subscription();

this.subscriptions.add(myObs1.subscribe(value => { /* do something */ }));
this.subscriptions.add(myObs2.subscribe(value => { /* do something */ }));

// unsubscribe
this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();
```